# ModSec Head Scratcher - Rule Exceptions ignored

Tags: mod-security

Sorry if this is a "noob" mistake, which I am sure it is, but I can't figure out why ModSec is ignoring my rule exception.

Situation (Debian 10): I have a ssl secured url for Monit monitoring software, that works on [www.example.com:3286](http://www.example.com:3286) , which as verified by my Apache2 error logs, triggers modsec rule id 920350 thereby blocking my access to the Monit web GUI.

I used `echo "SecRuleRemoveById 920350" >> /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf` to append the rule exception to modsecurity.conf (went back and verified its presence). Then restarted apache. Rule ignored.

So then, I tried adding the exception directly to the vhost of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) using:

```
<ifModule mod_security2.c>
         SecRuleRemoveById 920350
   </ifModule>
```

Then restarted apache, and the exception was ignored again.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Rule 920350 is flagged when the `Host` header of a request is an IP address, as opposed to a host name like example.com. Are you happy to ignore when clients connect by IP address?

Your `SecRuleRemoveById` rule exclusion, where is it in relation to the `Include` directive for the Core Rule Set? That is probably the key, here.